# GTIN number Google Shopping

Tags: gtin

I'm new to Google Shopping. We have been required to use GTIN number for our products. I understand this GTIN number has to be unique. But is it enough to be unique for only our products. Or it has to be a unique value in the world??

Answer (score 1):

**Each complete GTIN is unique for the whole world.**

A GTIN is a
[Global Trade Item Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number).
There are several types of GTIN,
including

- [Universal Product Code (UPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code), common in North America
- [International Article Number (IAN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number), common in Europe and Japan
- [International Standard Book Number (ISBN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)
- etc.

Typically a particular type of GTIN has 4 parts,

- a "group indicator" (typically indicating the country a national registration agency is in),
- a "manufacturer code" (typically a number that the business buys from a national registration agency for a small fee; the agency makes sure each business in that country gets a unique number.),
- a "product code" (the manufacturer is responsible for making sure each of its kinds of products gets a different product code), and
- a checksum.

This way each kind of product can be assigned a number unique across the whole world.

Some manufacturers stamp their product with not only a GTIN for that model of product, but also a serial number counting how many of that model has been manufactured.

Google says

> "Some products don’t have a GTIN assigned, and so you don’t need to
>   submit one. However, if the product does have a GTIN assigned and you
>   don’t submit it, then the product could be disapproved."
>   -- ["Products without a GTIN"](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I miss read it.

Based on my past setup with Google, gtin can be left blank if you don't have.

mpn can be any unique number which identifies your products uniquely.